# Is the compiled version of a binary dynamically linked to the system SSL library?

Tags: compiling, nginx, shared-library, openssl, dynamic-linking

In my case I build nginx from source and I want to confirm whether I need to rebuild it whenever a new OpenSSL update is released. From what I understand either of these two commands can be used to show dynamically linked libraries ([with the second being safer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd)):

```
ldd /path/to/binary_file
objdump -p /path/to/binary_file | grep NEEDED
```

If I see output like this:

```
objdump -p nginx | grep NEEDED | grep -i ssl
NEEDED               libssl.so.1.0.0
```

does that mean that OpenSSL is dynamically linked and nginx does not require a rebuild whenever the system copy of the OpenSSL library is upgraded (just a restart)?

I think the answer is Yes, but I'd just like to get confirmation that is the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that means it is dynamically linked. If the library were statically linked it would have been incorporated into the object code of the binary and ldd/objdump would not show the library name.

Comment: Thanks bain. I appreciate you taking the time to respond and confirm what I was hoping is true.

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as accepted if it has answered your question.

Comment: I think I've done it. Would you have to believe that I had to Google for how to do do so? I didn't even notice the grayed out check mark. I was looking around for a button or a link for "Mark as solved" and didn't see it when I first saw your question.